# Change of field attribute in runtime

Tags: php, symfony

Let's say we have a form defined in a form builder like this:

```
    $builder
        ->add('username', 'text', ['disabled' => false]);
```

Can we change the attribute `disabled` of a `form.username` field after the `$form` instance was created?

I have found that you can get the attributes with

```
$formBuilder->get('username')->getAttributes('data_collector/passed_options')['data_collector/passed_options']
```

and then replace with the `setAttributes` correspondingly.

But it looks super-dirty.

Another alternative I've found is to `$formBuilder->remove` and `->add()` the element back. Which is ugly as well.

So, any proper way to set it?

The scenario: the form is built, then validated, in case if it's invalid I need to mark a field disabled and render it once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simplified example which demonstrates how to manipulate with dynamic form elements, the name field is disabled by default and will be enabled only if member number is provided:

```
class ExampleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('member_number', 'integer', array(
                'required' => false
            ));

        $f = function(FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();
            $attr = array('disabled' => true);


            if (isset($data) && $data['member_number']) {
                unset($attr['disabled']);
            }

            $form->add('name', 'text', $attr);

        };
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, $f);
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, $f);        
    }
```

Comment: It is ugly as well, but formally it answers the question, thanks. In the project I would `remove-add` it instead - 2 lines is better maintainable than 10+ and events.

Comment: I believe this is actually the recommended way of dealing with dynamic elements, however I agree that it does look cumbersome

Comment: "the recommended way" --- for being recommended it's too limited, anyway,  it does not matter :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use form events for this. FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT is probably  the one you're after

[Check the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) especially [dynamic generation for submitted forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms), some good examples there.

Comment: Could you please show how exactly I **change the attribute** of the already added element (since that's what my question was about)

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but I think you could use the `buildView` and update it there.

```
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $view->offsetGet('username')->vars['disabled'] = false;
}
```